# Is it possible to have the name of the executable without the path?

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

Hi I'm trying to use the name of the executable and an usage string, I'm using `argv[0]` for such purpose but instead of the name of the executable itself it gives me the complete path to it.

Is there any way to get only the executable name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just search for the last /.

```
const char *exename = strrchr(argv[0], '/');
if (exename)
    // skip past the last /
    ++exename;   
else
    exename = argv[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, (on linux, at least) you just have to extract the executable name from the char* yourself.

The easiest way to do that is to use `basename(argv[0])`, which you can get by including "libgen.h".

Comment: Er, you mean like basename() in the standard C library? ;)

Comment: It's not standard C. It is in POSIX.

Comment: Should `basename` actually be used directly on `argv[0]`? The man page of `basename` states: *Both  dirname()  and basename() may modify the contents of path, so it may be desirable to pass a copy when calling one of these functions.*

Answer (score 1):

If it's available on your platform, there's a function `char *basename(char *path)`. See [basename documentation](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/basename.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use GetModuleFileName http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx with the handle argument = 0

Comment: Only if he only wants to compile on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Just use the last part of the path-string. Some combination of a call to `strrchr` (get last path delimiter) and e.g. `strcpy` or similar to copy out the part from last path delimiter to end

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getprogname()` if the name of the program is set by your OS.